# How to use request.body array in where clause with sequelize in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to search multiple elements from database with sequelize. I am using in operator to use this.

It works when I write $in : [1,2]

But when I write $in: [req.body.regions] //it does not work. How can I parse body object to an array.

```
Phones.findAll({
                attributes: ['id', 'enabled', 'color_id', 'sold', 'region_id'
                ],
                where: {
                    region_id: (req.body.region_id) ? { $in : [req.body.region_id]}: { $ne: null },
                    color_id: (req.body.color_id) ? { $in : [req.body.color_id]} : { $ne: null },
                    phone_model_id: (req.body.phone_model_id) ? { $in : [req.body.phone_model_id]} : { $ne: null },
                    enabled: 1,
                },
```

[image: Postman example]

Comment: Please post the output of `req.body`

Comment: @VivekDoshi I append screenshot of postman

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** : As I can see the request is comma separated , you can use the below one :

```
{ $in : req.body.region_id.split(",") }
```

---

**Good way to do** : it should be `regions[0], regions[1]` or just repeat same name `regions[]` in your postman api , then in your code use it like :

```
{ $in : req.body.regions }
```

First method is easy for you to test in postman but for developers the second way is more elegant and easy to create or maintain array rather than comma separated string

Comment: Great answer. But if array's size is greater than 100? It affect on speed?

Comment: @Benfactor , nope :)

Comment: @Benfactor , send me yours

Answer (score 0):

If

```
req.body.regions
```

is an array use this code:

```
$in: req.body.regions
```

Comment: It does not works. I will send property with postman. x-www-form. For example regions = 1,2

Comment: use "application/json" format. and if you want to parse req.body to json use JSON.parse(req.body)

Comment: I solve problem. I change key with regions[0], regions[1]. But when regions be 100? It effects on speed?

Comment: No 100 is a bit for this systems :)